# How to implement 3D / tilt mode in mapview?

Tags: android, google-maps, 3d, android-mapview

If you check the Google Maps application for Android, there are 3 modes available to display the listview. One of the modes available in Google Maps is the tilt mode wherein the map is displayed in 3D. The map also rotates when the user changes his direction.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Perhaps, with perspective projection/mapping, like in 3d shooting games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to an Android MapView allowing you to do that, you currently do not have those capabilities available via the SDK.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to MapView. Is there any way to achieve that if it's not available at Google's API by default?

Answer (score 1):

You should use accelerometer/gyroscope to achieve that.

please check out [Sensor Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) and its examples!